# how to use enableVersionHeader to turn off server signature of my web site IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, http-headers, web-config

I was searching to find out how to turn off the server signature of my website and I followed this link below

http://www.aliencoders.org/content/hiding-sensitive-header-response-for-iis-server/

in number 3 of the article it said that I should put this code

```
<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
```

in the `system.web` of my web.config

and I put it like this

```
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />

</system.web>
```

but the problem is that when I put this line `<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />` my website is go down and confront with Error 500.
what shall I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code you will write and change your old codes

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
```